# Mocking raw String in unit testing for Spring Boot service layer

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am trying to write unit tests for a service layer method finding `Player`s by name. The method calls a JPA repository method and returns a Page object.
I want the test to verify that the correct method from repository was indeed called.

**The test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PlayerService.class})
public class PlayerServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    PlayerService playerService;

    @MockBean
    PlayerRepository playerRepository;


    @Test
    public void whenListPlayersByName_thenShouldCallFindMethodWithPageableArgAndNameArg(){
        Pageable pageableStub = Mockito.mock(Pageable.class);
        String name = "xxx";
        Mockito.when(playerRepository.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(any(String.class), any(Pageable.class)))
                .thenReturn(any(Page.class));

        //1st attempt:
        //playerService.listPlayersByName(name, pageableStub);
        playerService.listPlayersByName(eq(name), pageableStub);

        verify(playerRepository).findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(any(String.class), any(Pageable.class));
    }
```

**My problem**

The test fails with a message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.domin0x.player.PlayerServiceTest.whenListPlayersByName_thenShouldCallFindMethodWithPageableArgAndNameArg(PlayerServiceTest.java:60)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Following the advice I changed the `name` to `eq(name)` but that results in a different issue:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
com.domin0x.player.PlayerRepository#0 bean.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(
    <any java.lang.String>, <any org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable>);

Actual invocation has different arguments:
com.domin0x.player.PlayerRepository#0 bean.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(
null,     Mock for Pageable, hashCode: 309271464
;
```

Any advice what should I change in the test?

**The service class**

```
@Service
public class PlayerService {
    public Page<Player> listPlayersByName(String name, Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(name, pageable);
    }
```

**The repository interface**

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Integer> {

    Page<Player> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: I don't see `eq()` used anywhere. I see `any()` used a few places. Are you sure the code you shared is the same code being used?

Comment: I think I found your problem, added answer for it.

Comment: I posted the `playerService.listPlayersByName` call without using `eq()` because that was my original attempt. I edited the test method code now to make it clearer.

Comment: Did you see my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this one out.

in `thenReturn`, you are calling `any(Page.class)`.  Instead, you should return either an actual `Page` object, or a mock `Page` object).

It's also better to avoid using "any" unless you have no way to know the identity.

```
Page<Player> pageStub = (Page<Player>)Mockito.mock(Page.class);
Mockito.when(playerRepository.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(name, pageableStub))
            .thenReturn(pageStub);

Page<PlayerStub> result = playerService.listPlayersByName(name, pageableStub);

assertSame(pageStub, result);

// No need to call verify, since it couldn't get pageStub without calling the correctly stubbed method.
```

To clarify:  `eq()`, `any()`, and other "matchers" should only be used as arguments to methods in `when` and `verify`.  They should never be passed to  the test subject, nor returned from any mocked object.

Comment: I accepted your answer but please change the 1st line in your solution to `Page<Player> pageStub = Mockito.mock(Page.class);` (or something similair). As of now, that code won't compile beacuse of a typo: you have declared `playerStub` but used `pageStub`. Also the Page class im using is from `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` which is abstract but that's on me as I haven't specified it in my question.

Comment: I updated my answer. FWIW, you could have made the edit yourself.